# How to retrieve the current authenticated user using OpenID?

Tags: java, json, servlets, openid

I'd like to create a Java servlet that talks to an OpenID end-point, and returns JSON containing the user's email address { "email": "email@example.com" } if the user is logged-in, and a friendly error message such as { "error": "No user is logged in." }. From the client's (web browser's) point-of-view, a request is being made to the above servlet and one of the above two types of responses are received: no redirects, or login screens.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague for stackoverflow, but I'd suggest using Spring Security to connect to an OpenID provider.  See http://krams915.blogspot.ie/2011/02/spring-security-3-openid-login-with_13.html for a tutorial using Spring Security and Google OpenID.